# convert jQuery to Prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

I have this jQuery script I'm trying to implement om Magento and I've tried usin noConflict but it still doesn't work. Magento runs prototype...I don't know any prototype so how would I go about converting this script from jQuery to Prototype?!

```
        var active = 0; // starts at zero
        var list = $('ul');

        list.children('li').eq('0').siblings().hide(); // Hide all except first list element

        $('.next').bind('click', function() {
            active = active == list.children('li').length-1 ? 0 : active + 1;
        });

        $('.prev').bind('click', function() {
            active = active == 0 ? list.children('li').length-1 : active - 1;
        });

        var getActive = function() {
            return list.children('li').eq(active);
        };

        $('.prev,.next').bind('click', function() {
            getActive().fadeIn().siblings().hide();
        });
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What difficulties did you encounter in that process? Don't expect posting some code using language A and ask people to convert it to language B without showing your efforts. This question will get closed very quickly if you don't update it. I am afraid that the first close votes might start to rain very soon. At least mine won't take long.

Comment: I tried changing all the $ -> $$ as I read the prototype works that way. I get an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'children' of null. So I guess there is something weird with the 3rd line as well.

Comment: show us please the full code you have tried. If all you did is change `$` to `$$` it's not surprising that your code doesn't work. In prototype there are not the same methods. A good place to start for you in this case is the prototype documentation: http://api.prototypejs.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **Look at a line**, for example `var list = $('ul');`
2. **Determine what it does**? A: It uses the `'ul'` selector to grab some elements.
3. **Determine how to do that thing in Prototype**. You can use [Google](https://www.google.com/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=how+to+select+elements+in+prototype&pbx=1&oq=how+to+select+elements+in+prototype&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=1615l5723l0l5994l35l20l0l8l8l0l207l2163l10.9.1l25l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=4fe41488848db57f&biw=1280&bih=899) or [Prototype's documentation](http://api.prototypejs.org/Prototype/Selector/select/). Here we find `Prototype.Selector.select(expression[, root = document]) → [Element…]`
4. **Repeat** for remaining lines

Optional step 5: If at any point along the way you have **a more specific problem**, come back and ask about it.

Comment: Yeah I agree! I deserve that downgrade. babysteps.

Comment: Let us know how you progress. I think you'll find that many are eager to help out and "teach you to fish" as your problem becomes more focused.